# How can I get roles and channels of a guild

Tags: discord.js

I am fairly new to making discord bots and I am making a !serverinfo command. The problem I have is that I cant get the channels and the roles, and the roles cannot be clickable(colored)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<Guild>.roles.cache` or `<Guild>.channels.cache` to return the respective manager. Replacing `<Guild>` with your guild object, most likely you will use `<Message>.guild`

Example

```
message.guild.channels.cache
// Will return Collection [Map] of all the guild's channels

message.guild.roles.cache
// Will return Collection [Map] of all the guild's roles
```

Comment: I know but how do I make it show up in an embed list. It will show up make object and if I iterate through, it will show the channel/role id and then the tag

Comment: Your question is titled *How can I get roles and channels of a guild* and you state that *The problem I have is that I cant get the channels and the roles*. I have provided the answer relevant to this question. If you need help with another issue consider posting another question and be sure to clearly state what your exact problem is.

Comment: I cant tell exactly what i want